# Detect USB to send USB Serial using Android Tablet

Tags: java, android, winforms, serial-port, usb

I would like to ask how to get and detect the USB.

1. The red one wire connect to usb to have 2 connections
2. The second wire connect to CPU to debug using Android Studio
3. Connect to terminal like printer(this one i want to connect but i cant figure it out how to detect and send data from this).

because I'm trying to send data from the serial port, but the thing here is that the device has 3 usb ports. Its similar to COM PORTS in windows.

I'm using Java and Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand your questions, but I assume you want to connect your android tablet to your PC over USB to debug your software on it. And you want to debug some software that connects over USB to a printer?

Comment: no, i mean i need to detect the printer, that's my question, I tried to use this https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart but  the PeripheralManager is not working

Comment: i found a new solution but the things this library needs api 27 higher https://developer.android.com/things/training/first-device/create-studio-project